Looking for Documentary about Hypothetical Extraterrestrial Life
I'm looking for the name of a documentary I watched late at night some time between 2005 and 2006 (it looked new, so it was likely made the year I saw it). It was likely on the discovery channel or the history channel (in America).
If I recall correctly the documentary was either a 1 or 2 hour special and not a continuous series.
The documentary focused on a hypothetical extraterrestrial world teeming with unique life forms. The documentary would introduce one creature at a time, talk about it's characteristics, what it eats, how it moves and how it fits in with the other life on the planet.
I recall one of the creatures being a gigantic 4-legged creature that would plant itself into the ground and absorb nutrients from the ground around it. Once it had drained the surrounding area of nutrients, the creature would un-plant itself and move to another spot.
Another creature had 2 forearms that ended in spikes, and also had wings but could only glide like a flying squirrel. It would glide from tree to tree and use it's spiked forearms to puncture the trunk of the trees and would sustain itself on the fluids of these trees.
I also recall a part where the documentary talked about the robotic probes we might send to this planet. There where 2, each with a form of artificial intelligence, and each one had slightly different programming; one was made to be more curious and would take more risks, while the other was designed to prioritize safety.
Any help finding this would be greatly appreciated. I'd love to watch this again.
